# How to reduce gap between body content and footer

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am having a wordpress website and using "generate press" theme but I have noticed that there is a big space between the content and that of the footer, can anyone please help me in reducing that space

I tried using custom css but is not working , I am expecting someone to help me out

this is my website link : https://baradice.nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `<div class="site-footer"> ... </div>`,

There is another `<div class="footer-width-fixer"> ...</div>` taking large empty space

You can add CSS like to hide large empty element:

```
.footer-width-fixer{
   display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad but the actual class was :   .e-parent